# Html not loading properly

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I have 10 html which are stored in an array...I want to display each html by means of button click...But my app got crashed.. Here is the code..

```
int xpos=10,ypos=10;

for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {

    UIButton *but=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [but setTag:i];
    but.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    but.frame=CGRectMake(xpos, ypos, 50, 50);
    xpos+=90;

    [self.view addSubview:but];
    [but addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}


- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSString *str=[array objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:str ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
    [webview release];
}
```

How to overcome this problem? here is the crash report

24/10/11 4:56:08 PM Loading HTML[4655]  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:]: nil string parameter'

Comment: Posting the error log statement may help.

Comment: A log would help. But why you release webview at the end of buttonClicked: ? this is maybe the reason of the issue (referencing a deallocated object)

Comment: I removed that,still the same pblm exist

Answer (score 1):

Where you are initializing the webview?

Please remove the `[webview release];` and try now.

Comment: I think tat may nt be the pblm...... This pblm exist only if I load the html dynamically (i.e if i call from array by means of tag)

Answer (score 0):

```
24/10/11 4:56:08 PM Loading HTML[4655] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '* -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:]: nil string parameter'
```

Your error log states that you are sending nil for the value **str**.

Please check the value of str. That should fix the problem. May be you have misspelled the name of the file.

---

**Update for comment**

Try replacing your file name there instead of getting it at run time.

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourHtmlFileNameGoesHere" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

If the above works then you should be checking the array.

Comment: I ve traced the value of str.....I can get the data from the array according to the tag of button...

Comment: This pblm exist only if I load the html dynamically (i.e if i call from array by means of tag)

Comment: If you are sure that you get the right value for str, try the below.
NSLog(@"your str value %@", str); [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str] ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:str ofType:@"html"]` results in nil - which means that the file could now be found in your main bundle. Make sure that file with that name and extension exists. Remember that file names are case sensitive.